# is there a safe way to convert a pressflow website to drupal 6?

Tags: 6

I have a website that was built on Pressflow, and the client wants to upgrade it to Drupal 7.

Is there a way to convert Pressflow to Drupal 6?

Comment: So you want to upgrade to D6 or D7?

Comment: I want to convert the pressflow codebase to drupal 6

Comment: If this is Pressflow D6, then you should be able to replace the Pressflow core by D6 core without making any other changes. However, the site won't necessarily work as before if you are using any of the Pressflow features such as cache headers.

Answer (score 1):

Pressflow and Drupal are API compatible, so you can simply replace Pressflow with the equivalent version of Drupal core. The only snag may come if someone has used private Pressflow functions in their module code on the site - but this is highly unlikely.

To upgrade, you can follow the normal upgrade path, which is to go to the highest version of Pressflow first, then upgrade to Drupal 7 or Pressflow 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give www.getpantheon.com a try, install a test Drupal 7 site and import your DB and code to safely test things out before going live with migration.

Answer (score 0):

I unzipped D6 over Pressflow6 on our quite large site. Nothing bad happened. :)